# TcpProxy running in Docker not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When I run a NodeJS TcpProxy (the one below) in my localhost, it works (I mean, it console.logs "Hi" when visiting localhost through a browser). But, when I launch a container with that same program inside it, it doesn't work.

TcpProxy code (index.js):

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    console.log("Hi");
}).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');

console.log("TCP server accepting connections on port: 80");
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM fedora-nodeJS # Just a custom image with fedora and nodeJS
ADD index.js /
EXPOSE 80
CMD node index
```

Then I just create the image ("docker build -t proxy .") and ("docker run -p 80:80 -P proxy").

Considerations:

- I've tried to repeat the same process changing the port numbers, and nothing changes.
- It console.logs *TCP server accepting connections on port: 80* but nothing happens when I enter to localhost.
- When running the "docker ps -a" command, it shows the container is running and localhost port 80 is mapping to container port 80 (TCP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script listens on 127.0.0.1, which is your local loopback device.
In this case its the loopback device of your container, not 'your' localhost.
I am assuming that `expose` and `-p` are publishing the port of the ip address of your container to your host. Not its loopback device.

So you need to listen on your external ip address. Try listening to 0.0.0.0